# Converting a list of instants to a list of increments

Tags: python, numpy

I need to convert a list of instants `a` to a list of increments `da`, for example from a list

```
a=[1.,3.,4.,8.]
```

I want the list

```
da=[2.,1.,4.]
```

Doing it "manually" is quite straightforward:

```
da=[]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    da.append(a[i+1]-a[i])
```

Does python offer a more synthetic and elegant way to do this, without the `for` loop?

A solution in the case `a` is a numpy array rather than a list would also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has a [`diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) function that does just this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.,3.,4.,8.])

np.diff(a)
# array([2., 1., 4.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the numpy tag:

```py
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1., 3., 4., 8.])

da = a[1:] - a[:-1]
da
array([2., 1., 4.])
```

While one can think that `np.diff` is faster, it is actually slightly slower, checking performance:

```py
import timeit
import pandas as pd

def timeit_diff(s):
    a = np.random.rand(s)

    t0 = timeit.default_timer()
    np.diff(a)
    return timeit.default_timer() - t0

def timeit_shift(s):
    a = np.random.rand(s)
    t0 = timeit.default_timer()
    a[1:] - a[:-1]
    return timeit.default_timer() - t0

sizes = [10**i for i in range(10)]

times = [[s, timeit_diff(s), timeit_shift(s)] for s in sizes]

df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=['size', 'diff_method', 'difference'])

df.set_index('size', inplace=True)
df
            diff_method  difference
size                               
1              0.000031    0.000004
10             0.000011    0.000002
100            0.000009    0.000010
1000           0.000027    0.000004
10000          0.000020    0.000013
100000         0.000827    0.001420
1000000        0.007460    0.009606
10000000       0.061235    0.061254
100000000      0.641381    0.597128
1000000000    23.763331   18.087844

df.plot(figsize=(12,8))
```

[image]